# Does the overall p-value of a multiple regression trump the individual ones?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, modeling

Here's my situation:

In theory, $y = f(x1, x2,...,x5)$, and the exact equation is context dependent.

In practice, I don't have data for $x4$ and $x5$ as yet.

Based on the somewhat promising results of analysis with $y$, $x1$, $x2$, and $x3$, I'd like to make the case for further investment to obtain data for $x4$ and $x5$ and repeat the analysis. If that provides a better fit, it could lead to actionable insights.

Regression results so far on a dataset with 100+ samples look like this:

**y ~ x1** has $R^2$ of **42%** with p-value less than 5%

**y ~ x1+x2** has $adj.R^2$ of **48%** with p-value of x1 and overall p-value less than 5% **but p-value of x2 is 20%**

**y ~ x1+x3** has $adj.R^2$ of **45%** with p-value of x1 and overall p-value less than 5% **but p-value of x3 is 13%**

**y ~ x1+x2+x3** has $adj.R^2$ of **51%** with p-value of x1 and overall p-value less than 5% **but p-value of x2 is 20% and x3 is 13%**

Residual plots for all of the above show significant bias which I attribute to missing $x4$ and $x5$.

Given that the overall p-values are always less than 5%, is it okay to conclude that the analysis so far explains 51% of the variation in $y$ or should I be mindful of the not-so-great p-values of $x2$ and $x3$ and go with 42%?

Comment: Could you explain how a p-value might lead to "actionable insights"?  One would think the latter would depend on the *sizes of the effects* of the additional variables and would have almost nothing to do with p-values of existing variables.

Comment: The "it" in "it could lead to actionable insights" refers to the model, not to p-values. p-values, in this context, influence the choice of the model (along with adj. R-squared).

Comment: These p-values should not influence the choice of model.  Most of them are irrelevant to model selection or are misleading.  None of them are relevant to your underlying question concerning whether to collect data for $x_4$ and $x_5.$

Comment: That's not the underlying question. Not sure how you got that impression. Anyway, of the four models described in the post, would you just go with the last one (51%) as the one that best explains y without any consideration of the p-values of the predictors?

Comment: "I'd like to make the case for further investment to obtain data for x4 and x5 and repeat the analysis" is the question I can see.

Comment: My opinion --- to cut to what I think is heart of the question --- in looking at a model, you can look at the *p*-value for the overall model without being overly concerned about the *p*-values for the individual terms.  ...  If you have reason to think a model should include x1, x2, and x3, or include x1, x2, x3, x4, and x5, then you have reason to fit this model.  ...

Comment: ... An increase in adjusted r-squared may be informative also.  .... Also note that *p*=0.05 isn't a magic cutoff.  In the case of multiple regression, you might decide that a *p* value of, say, < 0.20 is potentially "interesting, if you want to use *p* values as some sort of guide. ...

Comment: ...  The "bias" you see in the residuals may suggest that you should measure x4 and x5, or it may suggest that your model isn't the best for other reasons.  Perhaps you can add polynomials, transformations, or interactions of your variables.  Or perhaps a *generalized* linear model may be more appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Answer from my comments***

In looking at a model, you can look at the *p*-value for the overall model without being overly concerned about the p-values for the individual terms.

If you have reason to think a model should include *x1*, *x2*, and *x3*, or include *x1*, *x2*, *x3*, *x4*, and *x5*, then you have reason to fit the model with the variables you think should be included.

An increase in adjusted *r-squared* may be informative, especially if you don't have any clear reason to include or not include certain variables.  You might also use AIC, BIC, or AICc to evaluate models.

Also note that *p = 0.05* isn't a magic cutoff. In the case of multiple regression, you might decide that a *p*-value of, say, < 0.20 is potentially "interesting", ***if you want to use p values as some sort of guide***.

The "bias" you see in the residuals may suggest that you should include *x4* and *x5*, or it may suggest that your model isn't the best for other reasons. Perhaps you can add polynomials, transformations, or interactions of your variables. Or perhaps a generalized linear model may be more appropriate for your situation.